# How to use libproxy with proxy.pac?

Tags: proxy, proxy.pac

Has anyone here used Libproxy library? If I am to make an application to resolve proxy settings by reading proxy.pac from a remote server, would libproxy help me with that? Any ideas on how to use libproxy to download pac scripts and get the proxy values?

Thanks!

GK

Answer (score 0):

`Libproxy` handles the `pac` downloading and parsing transparently for you.

What your app should to:
Create a new `ProxyFactory` object `pf = New ProxyFactory()`

For every resource you connect to, check which proxies to use

```
ProxiesToTry=pf.getProxies("http://www.google.com")
```

(for every URI you connect! Especially with `PAC` this can be different per URI, like offloading pictures or videos and the like).

[...] connect to the proxy and do your communication

destroy `pf` object.

As long as the `pf` object is lying around, the `pac` file is being cached.

For futher info, feel free to join the devs on #libproxy on freenode (IRC)